# Python Regular Expression looking for two digits only

Tags: python, regex

If I had a sentence that has an age and a time :

```
import re
text = "I am 21 and work at 3:30"
answer= re.findall(r'\b\d{2}\b', text)
print(answer)
```

The issue is that it gives me not only the 21, but 30 (since it looks for 2 digits).  How do I avoid this so it will only count the numbers and not the non-alphanumeric characters that leads to the issue?  I tried to use [0-99] instead of the {} braces but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: Sorry, the answer it gives is 21 and 30 (the 3:30) using only the last two digits in the time.

Comment: Edit it on your main text rather than put it in the comment. Not all people read comments.

Comment: What do you mean by  "How do I avoid this so it will only count the numbers and not the non-alphanumeric characters "? "non-alphanumeric characters"?

Comment: i believe this is not your actual problem. what's your real problem? for example, do you want to catch 2 digits at the beginning of a string or at the end of one?

Comment: This does not match any non-numerical characters so you entire premise must be wrong.

Comment: Are times the only problem? Would you not want to pick up the `25` in `Today is February 25`?

Comment: For now, I just wanted to pick up two digit numbers that were separated by \b on either side.  I thought that the ":" was giving me issues, and thus called it alphanumeric, meaning a symbol that wasn't alpha / numbers. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Using `\s\d{2}\s` will give you only 2 digit combinations with spaces around them (before and after).

Or if you want to match without trailing whitespace: `\s\d{2}`

Comment: But it will fail on the not-too dissimilar "I work at 3:30 and I am 21".

Comment: "Easily fixed"... to something catching the `' 10'` in `'I work at 10:30'`.

Answer (score 2):

Thats because `:` is considered as non-word constituent character when you match empty string at word boundary with `\b`. In Regex term, **a word for `\b` is `\w+`**.

You can check for digits with space or start/end of input line around:

```
(?:^|\s)(\d{2})(?:\s|$)
```

**Example:**

```
In [85]: text = "I am 21 and work at 3:30"
    ...: re.findall(r'(?:^|\s)(\d{2})(?:\s|$)', text)
Out[85]: ['21']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `(?<!)(?!)` negative lookahead to isolate and capture only 2 (two) digits.

**Regex**: [`(?<!\S)\d{2}(?!\S)`](https://regex101.com/r/JkwPWz/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
^\d{2}$|(?<=\s)\d{2}(?=\s)|(?<=\s)\d{2}$|^\d{2}(?=\s)
```

that will match all the 21 in the following strings:

```
I am 21 and work at 3:30
21
abc 12:23
12345
I am 21
21 am I
```

**demo:** https://regex101.com/r/gP1KSf/1

Explanations:

1. `^\d{2}$` match 2 digits only string or
2. `(?<=\s)\d{2}(?=\s)` 2 digits surrounded by space class char or
3. `(?<=\s)\d{2}$` 2 digits at the end of the string and with a preceded by a a space class char
4. `^\d{2}(?=\s)` 2 digits at the beginning of the string and followed by a space class char