# RegEx for matching specific pattern in a Python list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string

Say, I have the following code:

```
import re
strings_of_text = ['data0', 'data23', 'data2', 'data55', 'data_mismatch', 'green']
strings_to_keep = []
expression_to_use = r'^\d{2}$|(?<=\s)\d{2}(?=\s)|(?<=\s)\d{2}$|^\d{2}(?=\s)'
    
for string in strings_of_text:
    # If the string is data#
    if (re.search(expression_to_use, string)):
        strings_to_keep.append(string)
print(strings_to_keep)
```

Where I am only concerned with adding strings with the pattern "data" followed by some number. So in this case, I would only want to add `'data0', 'data23', 'data2', 'data55'`

How can I do this? I am thinking I will need to `import re` but I'm not sure how to use it.

I have read this: [Python Regular Expression looking for two digits only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48978912/python-regular-expression-looking-for-two-digits-only)

But when I try to modify my regular expression using this expression

```
^\d{2}$|(?<=\s)\d{2}(?=\s)|(?<=\s)\d{2}$|^\d{2}(?=\s)
```

It does not work... This is where I am stuck. I am new to using regular expressions so thank you to all of those who post in advance

#### EDIT:

Here is the outcome I am trying to get:

```
print(strings_to_keep)
>>> ['data0', 'data23', 'data2', 'data55']
```

Comment: A desired output would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your pattern you are using 4 alternations but you are not taking the word `data` into account.

You could use [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) instead to start the match from the beginning of the string and use `data\d+$` to match data followed by 1+ digits until the end of the string:

```
import re
strings_of_text = ['data0', 'data23', 'data2', 'data55', 'data_mismatch', 'green']
strings_to_keep = []
expression_to_use = r'data\d+$'

for string in strings_of_text:
    # If the string is data#
    if (re.match(expression_to_use, string)):
        strings_to_keep.append(string)

print(strings_to_keep)
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/yjiDiz)

You might keep working with a filtered collection instead of creating a new one using for example filter:

```
import re
strings_of_text = ['data0', 'data23', 'data2', 'data55', 'data_mismatch', 'green']
strings_to_keep = []
expression_to_use = r'data\d+$'

strings_of_text = list(filter(lambda x: re.match(expression_to_use, x), strings_of_text))
print(strings_of_text)
```

Result

```
['data0', 'data23', 'data2', 'data55']
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/ExCI77)

Comment: You are welcome. Perhaps you can use filter or a list comprehension to keep only a single collection and prevent having to use a separate collection.

Comment: Nice solution. Is +$ really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `re.compile` if you are using the same pattern as it has less overhead.

```
strings_of_text = ['data0', 'data23', 'data2', 'data55', 'data_mismatch', 'green']

import re
engine = re.compile(r'data\d+$')
strings_to_keep = [s for s in strings_of_text if engine.match(s)]
print(strings_to_keep) # ['data0', 'data23', 'data2', 'data55']
```